# Return a table using SQL Procedure?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have problem with return table using SQL Procedure.

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE return_data(surname character varying)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT * FROM peopple WHERE surname=surname

$$;

CALL return_data('Jobs');
```

Currently the procedure executes without error but it doesn't return a table.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

A function can return but a procedure cannot. Thats true, I wanna add to that we generally use function to return values of one type (in general one value) 
While, 
Procedure never returns but can behave like a function without a return statement using OUT parameters. To add to this we use procedure when we dont wanna return in actual but executing sql statements but in case if we require a procedure to give multiple values we can make procedure behave like a function for multole values output vja OUT.

As a table can be accessed by record or array type depending upon homogenity. Therefore, use function with return type as record/array.

Hence, as function is solely used to return single output we have to specify via return.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer.  Functions can return one or multiple columns and one or more rows.  Procedures aren't really meant to return anything, but you can force them to by using INOUT parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Procedures aren't meant to return anything. Use a set returning function

```
create function return_data(p_surname varchar)
  returns setof people
as
$$
  select *
  from people
  where surname = p_surname;
$$
language sql;
```

You should also avoid parameter or variable names that have the same name as a column.

Then use it like this:

```
select *
from return_data('Jobs');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append one or more rows to the result set:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION return_data(surname character varying)
 RETURNS TABLE(firstname character varying, surname character varying, age integer)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT firstname, surname, age
        FROM users;
    END;
$function$
;
```

Invoke the function:

```
SELECT * FROM return_data("a surname");
```